# FTP - How to transfer a directory with multiple sub-directories?

Tags: ftp, directory

I need to transfer a few gigs of files from server A to B. I own SSH access to server A, but I have only FTP access to B.

Since I can not send one .tar file from A to B, for the reason that I can not untar it later, I need to perform an FTP transfer.

How can I transfer (via FTP) all files including the directories and all sub directories?

I tried using `mput *` and `mput *.*`, but they did not work.

**About solutions like LFTP or others**

The lftp is a great solution, but I can not install it on the server, because it is not a dedicated server or a VPS. It is a common shared webhosting with SSH access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a client that can handle this. lftp (mirror -R , see http://www.russbrooks.com/2010/11/19/lftp-cheetsheet ) and ncftp (put -R) are two.